# SoftLayer_User_Customer::updatePassword deprecated

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have been using the method SoftLayer_User_Customer::updatePassword for awhile.  I am now getting an error 500 Internal Server Error returned.

The content is `'{"error":"This method is deprecated.  Please see documentation for initiatePortalPasswordChange","code":"SoftLayer_Exception"}'`

The URL I use is `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/4719557/updatePassword` with a POST method

I looked at the method initiatePortalPasswordChange and it sends a password change email. We have designed a system where we change the password automatically using teh method updatePassword and it works perfectly for us.

What mwethod do I use now so we can change the password of a username with a REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to update your password through SoftLayer API or Control Portal. As you said, the only way is through method:

- [SoftLayer_User_Customer::initiatePortalPasswordChange](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/initiatePortalPasswordChange)

You can send an email to: PortalFeedback@softlayer.com with your comments or requirements.