# updatePassword deprecated, initiatePortalPasswordChange available in 2.2?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

So since updatePassword method is deprecated as per [SoftLayer_User_Customer::updatePassword deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227887/softlayer-user-customerupdatepassword-deprecated), is the new suggested method - using initiatePortalPasswordChange available in API version 2.2?

Comment: version 2.2? it seems you are using a client of solftlyaer (Python, Ruby, PHP) what client are you using? or what do you mean with version 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what are you talking about API version 2.2, currently the valid versions for the Softlayer API are 3 and 3.1 and for those version the methos is working

Comment: Using python : https://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/v2.2.0/api/client/

Comment: I have seem the code of the Python client version 2.2 and in the file consts.py I can see that the client is using the version 3.0 of the Softlayer API, so the method must work properly using the Pyhton clietn version 2.2